# Why datepicker in angular js clears multiselect check boxes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

All the checkboxes in multiselect box are selected. the moment i select date from datepicker , loading icon comes on screen and clears the checkboxes in multiselect box.[here is the image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0m7c.png)

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: drop some code in here

Comment: i dont have code for this . it is all bootstrap . when the page loads all the checkboxes are selected by default. then i move to datepicker to select start and end date . but the moment i select date from date picker it clears all the checkboxes . thats all.  u can refer the image i have atrached